# AWS serverless webpack with helper module for lambda (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, serverless, webpack-4

The current file structure that I have followed is -

MainApp

- package.json
- index.js

HelperApp

- package.json
- helper1.js
- helper2.js

While creating webpack for my MainApp which uses HelperApp (added in dependency of MainApp) faced issue while creating dist as
common modules were not there.